# How to show a Laravel array with first 50 characters of each row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a 4.2 Laravel array that Im building here, its translating the number value from one table to display the text value within a dropdown form I'm building. (for example #4 is Blue)

Some of the text is very long and I want to cut it down to say the first 50 characters to show in the dropdown. How would I go about doing that? Below are my snippets. So instead of showing "Blue is my favorite color and I like to watch the clouds..." I'd want it to say "Blue is my fav color and..."

Thanks

```
$Appinfo = finding::where('ID',$id)->first();
$active = finding::where('ID', $id)->pluck('fkey_target_id');
$AppTarget  = Target::where('id', '>', 0)->get();
$borat  = Target::where("ID", $active)->select('ID')->first();
$tempArray6 = [];
foreach($AppTarget as $entry6)
 {
   $tempArray6[$entry6->ID] = $entry6->target;
 }
$AppTarget = $tempArray6;
```

Here is my form

```
{{ Form::select('target', array('' =>  $AppTarget), $borat->ID, array('class' => 'form-control','data-fv-notempty' => 'false','data-fv-notempty-message'=>'Please input.')) }}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do a substr() http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php?

Comment: I'd post an example / answer, but it's really unclear what part of your code sets the output string you're wanting to echo.

Comment: {{ str_limit($value, 50) }}

Comment: @kenken9999 - the OP didn't mention Blade, also, it's acceptable to use the native PHP functions for things like this ;)

Comment: Ive tried using a substr() but that didnt seem to work in the blade form here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a new function in the controller, then return that function back using the str_limit. Doing it any other way in an array did work and it didnt work in the form on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Pure php way:

```
$longString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';

echo substr($longString, 0, 50).'...';
//Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
```

Laravel way ([str_limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-limit)):

```
str_limit($longString, 50);
```

While inside blade you can use both.
Example:

```
@php
    substr($longString, 0, 50).'...';
@endphp
```

or

```
{{ str_limit($longString, 50) }}
```

or

```
{{ substr($longString, 0, 50).'...' }}
```